# Advertising in youtube iframe API does not work on ipad, iphone and android

Tags: android, iphone, ipad, youtube, youtube-api

The ads are not displayed when accessing the site content through the iPad, iPhone and android.

The video usually works the problem is only the ads that do not display .

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Thank you for your attention

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

var player;
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('youtube-player', {
              height: '400',
              width: '100%',
              playerVars:{
                autoplay:1,
                showinfo:0,
                wmode:'transparent',
                controls:1
              },
              videoId: list_video[0],
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              }

            });
        }




<div id="youtube-player">
                            Player do Youtube
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a problem. **It's up to Google to decide how, where and when display an ads**. This imply that:

- If an ads is served using a specific technology (like Flash), then this ads could not be seen on some platform (like Android)
- If an ads is targeted on a user-agent-base it cannot be seen everywere
- and so on...

That's to say, if you are using the official API you are ok (despite of the ads' behavior).